# PHP Slim Get route placeholder in a container

Tags: php, slim

Is it possible get the value of a route placeholder within a Slim  container?  I know I can access the placeholder by adding a third parameter to the request but I'd like to have it injected so I'm not assigning it on each request.

I've tried $app->getContainer('router') but I can't seem to find a method to actually pull the placeholder value.

Example:

```
$app = new Slim\App;

$c = $app->getContainer();

$c['Controller'] = function() {
    $userId = // how do I get the route placeholder userId?
    return new Controller($userId);
};

$app->get('/user/{userId}','Controller:getUserId');

class Controller {
    public function __construct($userId) {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    public function getUserId($request,$response) {
        return $response->withJson($this->userId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without some 'hacky' things this will not work because we have no access on the request object build by slim, while the controller get constructed. So I recommend you to just use the 3rd parameter and get your userid from there.

The 'hacky' thing would be todo the same, what slim does when you execute `$app->run()`, but if you really want todo this, here you'll go:

```
$c['Controller'] = function($c) {
    $routeInfo = $c['router']->dispatch($c['request']);
    $args = $routeInfo[2];
    $userId = $args['userId'];
    return new Controller($userId);
};
```

Note: slim3 also urldecoded this values so may do this as well `urldecode($args['userId'])` [Source](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/App.php#L551)

Comment: It does work, but you are correct.  It's quite hacky.  If I were to implement it, I would probably create a global container to return a function to handle this.

Comment: @rob did you try my solution... its a bit hacky too (in my opinion not that much), but is more generic , and to have a maincontroller is a good thing too, you have access to the container in every controller

Comment: @SimonMüller I looked at it and it seems a bit overkill for what I'm after.  the answer jmattheis provided did solve my problem but has me thinking if the container really should have this responsibility or not.

Answer (score 1):

create a container wrapper and a maincontroller then extend all your controller from your maincontroller, then you have access to the container.

here is how i solved this problem:

https://gist.github.com/boscho87/d5834ac1ba42aa3da02e905aa346ee30

Comment: Pimple (the DI framework) automatically adds the container as constructor parameter, when not other definied, so there is no need for that.

Comment: but you have to write the sam code again in every controller .... just to hav access to the container, and in the maincontroller you can other things like a logger .... etc.

Comment: Nope, just like your maincontroller, the difference is that there is no CurrentController class, and the container will get passed through the constructor

Comment: how do you extend your controller from your MainController, when the MainController needs a constructor parameter, then you have the same in every controller

Comment: When you dont define the constructor in 'your controller' then the parent constructor will be executed, otherwise u need to todo `parent::__construct(..)`